# is is secure to use Upstash Redis fromEnv in Nextjs middleware or would I be leaking environmental variables to the browser?

Tags: next.js, redis, environment-variables, middleware, prisma

I have a middleware file written in JavaScript with Next.js.

My goal is to connect to a key-value database in middleware so that I can rewrite the incoming host to a predesignated external url. The object looks like this

`{ host: rewrite_url }`

I have been using Prisma with a different database service recently but ran into this error when trying to connect from middleware

```
- error node_modules/.prisma/client/index-browser.js (649:10) @ new PrismaClient
- error PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.
```

*** if anyone reading this is aware of this no longer being the case please let me know.

I did some research and based of what I read online I had assumed it was and so I decided to try an Upstash Redis Database instead and have been going off this guide https://docs.upstash.com/redis/quickstarts/nextjs13 which is meant to be used in the Nextjs 13 app dir.

I have a working implementation here
the middleware file looks like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { Redis } from '@upstash/redis'
import { getValidSubdomain } from '/lib/getValidSubdomain';

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;
const redis = Redis.fromEnv()

// i can see the variables are exposed to the console
console.log('redis object is ' + JSON.stringify(redis))

export async function middleware(req) {
  let url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  let host = req.headers.get('host');
  let rewriteUrl = await redis.srandmember(host)
  let hostString = JSON.stringify(host)
  let subdomain = getValidSubdomain(host);

  if (PUBLIC_FILE.test(url.pathname) || url.pathname.includes('_next')) return;

  if ((subdomain) && (hostString.includes(subdomain) === true)) {
    console.log('rewriting to new host: ' + rewriteUrl)
    url = rewriteUrl
  }

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
}
```

My question: Is it secure to use Upstash Redis `fromEnv()` like I have done here to obtain environmental variables in nextjs middleware? Or would I be exposing them in the browser or doing something insecure like prefixing an environmental variable with a `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, etc. I don't want to leak my database credentials to anyone on accident.

the .env file looks like

```
UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL="https://xxx"
UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN="xxx"
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated... Thanks in advance for your help and time.